# Spring ModelAndView não funcionando corretamente com o callback do AJAX

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

Bem, a algum tempo fiz uma funcionalidade em meu site que consiste em realizar um filtro (chamada *AJAX*), e na minha action eu simplesmente devolver uma *view* (no momento estou renderizando via *callback*, mas se for possível gostaria que o próprio *ModelAndView* fosse responsável por isso).

Chamada *AJAX*:

```
function perfectDestinationFilter(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/viatge/perfect-travel-filter",
        data: $('#form-filter-perfect-travel').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            $('html').html( response );
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

*Action* responsável em devolver minha pagina com os destinos encontrados:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/perfect-travel-filter", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getDestinations(@RequestParam String social, @RequestParam String economic, @RequestParam String trip, @RequestParam String weather, @RequestParam String general, Model model) throws SQLException{
        if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(social) || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(economic) || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(trip) || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(weather) || Strings.isNullOrEmpty(general)){
            return new ModelAndView("site/destinations02", "perfectDestinationError", true);
        }else{
            return new ModelAndView("site/destinations02", "perfectDestinations", destinationFacade.filterDestinations(economic, general, social, weather, trip));
        }

    }
```

Bem, essa abordagem até funciona por meio do *callback* (`$('html').html( response );`), mas o problema é que a pagina renderiza com *layout* quebrado e sem contar que algumas funções *jQuery* não funcionam perfeitamente.

Existe alguma outra possibilidade? Teria como eu evitar o callback deixando a responsabilidade a responsabilidade para o *TilesViewResolver* realizar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, trocando de resolver e jogando a responsabilidade para o tiles, você vai continuar devolvendo um html. Talvez o melhor jeito seria retornar um JSON com os destinos. Para fazer isso, anota o seu método com @ResponseBody e retorna diretamente a lista de destinos. Provavelmente você vai ter que adicionar a dependência do Jackson(serializador de json) no seu projeto também.